# Hibernate increment starting number

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, derby

I'm using hibernate to persist an entity to my database. For the moment it's a derby DB, but I will be moving it over to an oracle DB soon.

in my classname.hbm.xml I have the id defined as such:

```
<id name="id" type="long">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
```

How do I set the starting value for the id?  I'd like it to start at something like 10000 rather than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, it appears that IncrementGenerator works based off the highest primary key so unless you fix your primary keys (which I wouldn't recommend) you're stuck with that functionality.

Would recommend a different strategy, it isn't safe in a cluster of machines either...  Look at the Hibernate docs and maybe the enhanced identifier generators:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-enhanced

Answer (score 5):

"increment" isn't really a good idea for ID generation.

If you're moving to Oracle, then you'll use a sequence to generate IDs, and the sequence is controlled by oracle, so you can make it start with whichever value you want.

Derby support [sequences](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefsqljcreatesequence.html) as of 10.6, though you need Hibernate 3.6 to get it to [work](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5427)..

Answer (score 1):

Generator type *increment* looks up the maximum numeric primary key value in the table and increments it by one.

Generator type *native* uses a sequence when the underlying database used is Oracle. You can easily augment the value of the sequence to an arbitrary start value.