# How to give starting value to auto increment in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. How do I specify in Hibernate the starting value of my ID (say 100000) and auto increment the ID starting at this value in my code. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
@Id
@Column (name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
private Integer ID;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296826/hibernate-increment-starting-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetInitialValueOfTableGenerator.htm

JPA has a @TableGenerator annotation in which you can set an initial value.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way around this. I manually entered a row in the database with ID 1000000 and used the code mentioned in my question. The next time a add a record to this table, it takes 1000000 as the last value and starts incrementing from this value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if first required ID is 1000000, then use @TableGenerator but if first required ID is 1000001, then use @SequenceGenerator.

This article explains the difference in a very clear way:

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated